# Android Eclipse fail to import project

Tags: java, android, eclipse, 64-bit, ubuntu-13.10

please help me :(

I'm a beginner in this.

I have a 64 bits system with Ubuntu Gnome 13.10.

I wanted to start developing in Android. So I downloaded the Android SDK from here http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html extract the files and all the process. 
Then I did this : " sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre openjdk-7-jdk icedtea-7-plugin "

So I opened Eclipse and the message " error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1 " showed up in the console. I read I had to install some of the 32 bit libraries if I was using a 64 bit system, so put this in terminal: sudo apt-get install ia32-libs. It didn't work but tried with this : sudo apt-get install lib32z1 , sudo apt-get install lib32ncurses5 , sudo apt-get install lib32z1. The first and the third worked.

Thought everything was gonna be fine, opened Eclipse and Import a project, by File -> Import ... But all the code showed up with errors. Basically everything says "SomethingSomething cannot be resolved to a type" There are 85 errors like this.

Also, I noticed that my R.java is missing, I tried creating a new project, named it "R.java" and pasting the code and saving it. Didn't work.

I've tried on Project->Clean.  And Right click, Android Tools, Fix Project Properties. Both did nothing. Tried changing API target to the latest, 19, but nothing.

Read also that it could be the name of the package in the AndroidManifest.xml but everything appears to be fine in there.

I also would like to say that I can create new projects. It creates the R.java and it works just fine. It's just importing.

Could you please please help me?

Any answer will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Windows, but I think Eclipse is the same:
In Eclipse you have to go to Help-->Install new Software
There you enter you direction for the Android-Plugin.